# Is it possible to pass a parameter/variable to a Onblur function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to pass a parameter/variable to an Onblur function given that they are both a separate function and without using global variables and creating a closure function?

I Also don't want to call example() function as well, because it has other functions and an AJAX.

```
function example(){
//Stuff I don't want to repeat.
//Ajax load to get A
Var A='Reusable Data';
}

$('#buttonId').on("blur", function() {
console.log("I need"+ A);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not willing to use global variable, then you cant access a variable outside its scope, one thing you can do to get the value, its basically closure concept, and you can use example function object on other places if required.

```
function example(){
   Var A;

   return{
     getValue:function(){
       return A;
     }
  };
 }
var exObj = example();

$('#buttonId').on("blur", function() {
 console.log("I need"+ exOb.getValue());
}
```

**Edited**

```
function example(){
   Var A;

   return{
     getValue:function(fn){
        fn(A);
       },

  };
 }
var blurFunc = function(val) {
    console.log("I need"+ val;
}

$('#buttonId').on("blur", example().getValue(blurFunc));
```

Comment: But, I said no global variables and closure functions. :)

Comment: One thing can be done. You can create a function which handles blur, and  you can invoke that from example function.

Comment: function example(){
   Var A;

   return{
     getValue:function(fn){
      fn(A);
       },

  };
 }
var blurFunc = function(val) {
  console.log("I need"+ val;
}

$('#buttonId').on("blur", example().getValue(blurFunc));

Comment: To make it would be against the concept of js.

Comment: Well to access some variable outside its scope without using closure is also not a good practice. I am just suggesting the way to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: I mean my question is against the concept of js. So I made your answer the answer.

Answer (score 1):

in Jquery you can pass data when registering event handlers.

More Info: http://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data

```js
function example() {
  //Stuff I don't want to repeat.
  //Ajax load to get A
  var A = 'Reusable Data';

  return function() {
    return A;
  }
}

$('#buttonId')
  .on(
    "click", 
    { getValue: example() },
    function(event) {
      var a = event.data.getValue();
      alert("I need " + a);
    }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonId">test</button>
```

I changed the event from `blur` to `click` for the demo but this will work with any event.

Comment: example() will be called again when onclick triggers, though.

Comment: `example` will get called again but it is just a getter for a variable with no computation inside it so it is equal to just passing a value. Moreover, if value of `A` changes multiple times in a page's lifecycle (just in case), this solution will handle it.

Comment: "//Stuff I don't want to repeat.//Ajax load to get A"
They are just pseudo codes. In real, the code has an Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the `var A` from function `example()`. And then you can access `var A` by accessing the function directly.

```
function example(){
//Ajax load to get A
Var A='Reusable Data';
return A;
}

$('#buttonId').on("blur", function() {
console.log("I need"+ example());
}
```

**EDIT**

Make it global (I won't suggest you that)

```
var A;
function example(){
A='Reusable Data';
return A;
}

$('#buttonId').on("blur", function() {
console.log("I need"+ example());
}
```

Comment: What if you don't want to repeat function example() just because you need A? Would I be able to call an inner function exampleinner() that can return the A only?

Comment: But Global variables are frowned upon :(

Comment: You need to learn OOP then. Use class and methods concept. :) If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.

Comment: that's why I asked if there is a way without using a global variable.

Comment: If you are trying to access a variable outside its scope in a indirect manner then you are indirectly making it global and making it accessible to rest of the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably wrap both functions on a IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) and bind the event on the success of your ajax call

```
(function(){
   function example(){
       $.ajax.........done(function(response){
          bindOnBlurEvent(response);
       });
   }
   function bindOnBlurEvent(response){
      //bind the event with the response
   }
}());
```

Comment: That would be considered a closure though.

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted, "without using global variables and creating a closure function".